# Tracking tensor shape at graph creation time

Tags: python, tensorflow

In some cases, tensorflow seems to be able inspect the values of tensors at graph creation time, and in other cases this fails.

```
>>> shape = [constant([2])[0], 3]
>>> reshape([1,2,3,4,5,6], shape)
<tf.Tensor 'Reshape_13:0' shape=(2, 3) dtype=int32>
>>> zeros(shape)
<tf.Tensor 'zeros_2:0' shape=(?, 3) dtype=float32>
```

In the example above, reshape() can see that the tensor passed in as shape has a value of 2, and the resulting output has a shape of (2,3) but zeros() cannot and the static shape is (?,3). What is the reason for the difference?

My colleague posted [Determining tensor shapes at time of graph creation in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49038854/determining-tensor-shapes-at-time-of-graph-creation-in-tensorflow), which is based on the same underlying issue, but he was asking a slightly different question of how to best work with tensorflow to solve this kind of thing, whereas my question is about why tensorflow behaves this way.  Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TD;DR:

- `tf.reshape` can infer the shape of output but `tf.zeros` cannot;
- `shape` supports integers (as **static/definite**) and also Tensors (as **dynamic/indefinite**) for both functions.

---

Codes are more concrete and more clear:

```
shape = [tf.constant([2])[0], tf.constant([3])[0]]
print(tf.reshape([1,2,3,4,5,6], shape))  
# Tensor("Reshape:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=int32)
print(tf.zeros(shape))  
# Tensor("zeros:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=float32)
```

and this:

```
shape = [tf.constant([5])[0], 3]
print tf.reshape([1,2,3,4,5,6], shape)  
# Tensor("Reshape:0", shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32)
# This will cause an InvalidArgumentError at running time!
```

When using a `Tensor` (like `tf.constant([2])[0]`) as `shape` to create another `Tensor` (like `tf.zeros(shape)`), the shape is always indefinite at graph creation time. However, `tf.reshape()` is different. It can infer the shape of the output using the shape of the input and the given shape (of static part).

In your code, `3` is a static integer and the shape of the input is given(`[6]`); the shape `(2, 3)` is obtained in fact by inferring, instead of being provided. This can be proved in the second part of codes. Although I give a `tf.constant([5])`, the shape does not change. (No error at graph creation time but raised an error at running time!)

Comment: Yes, I arrived at the same conclusion, that reshape was using the shape of the the first argument to infer what the output shape should be.